# jQuery Form Submit Function Ignored On Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to execute a function on form submit whenever another html element is changed. However, the function inside my form submit seems to be ignored.

```
$("element1").change(function(){
    alert("Works!");
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        console.log("Submitted!");
    });
});
```

The "Works!" alert displays but for some reason it will not print "Submitted!" to the console and I'm unsure why. Is it possible to execute a function within a form submit if it's being triggered by another element ".change" event? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention, I need my code to invoke a form submission when this field is changed. Ultimately, I'm having users upload a csv and after it's selected from the file explorer it submits the form. I would like to keep the user on the same page after the file is uploaded as well.

Comment: Two process needs to be done at the same time to run this code. logically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is trigger the submit function like this

```
$("#form").submit();//Triggers the submit function.
```

However, the code you have written is not the write way to write it.You don't want submit event to be binded to the form every time the element is changed.
So it can be rephrased as

```
/*In this case the event binding happens only once*/
$("#form").submit(function() {
    console.log("Submitted!");
});
/*Now simply trigger it when the element is changed*/
$("element1").change(function() {
    alert("Works!");
    $("#form").submit();
});
```

For you clear understanding have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khbL1ro9/)

Comment: Awesome this worked out for me! I didn't realize it worked in this fashion. Thanks!